# What is the main difference between the usage of Synchronization (member methods) and the Lock Interface?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, synchronization, locking

For example: I have two member methods (instance methods) inside a class, both marked with the key word "synchronized". If I have thread 1 accessing method 1, can method 2 be accessed by thread 2? If so, what's the difference between using synchronization to the Lock Interface? As far as I understand, Lock Interface allows us to lock in specific parts inside the code, but can it lock in different pieces of code inside a method, and let other parts unlocked, to be used by other threads?[I have this image to illustrate the matter: here I'm using the Lock Interface to lock in different pieces of code inside different methods](https://i.stack.imgur.com/184jC.jpg)

Comment: Please don’t post a picture of code.  Edit your question, and copy the code into your question as text, not as an image.

Comment: The general answer is:  Locks can provide more fine-grained access through the use of Conditions and “try…” methods, and can optionally distinguish between read locks and write locks.  Also, a thread waiting on a synchronization monitor cannot be interrupted, but Locks have methods which allow interruption.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.